# What/when could possibly break if I don't include \[\] around the color code in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was messing around with the color codes trying to understand how color code is used in bash script and I found that it works fine without including \[\] around it as in here:

This..

```
red="\033[38;5;203m"
export PS1="$red\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W"
```

..gives the same result as that:

```
red="\[\033[38;5;203m\]"
export PS1="$red\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W"
```

So is the second form necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your prompt contains non-printing characters
that are not enclosed in `\[`...`\]`,
then the shell will miscalculate the width of the prompt. 
As a result, it will be confused about where the cursor is,
and it will update the display erroneously. 
A classic example of this occurs
if you type a command so long that it's longer than the window is wide,
so it wraps to the next line,
and then you backspace back up to the first line.